# powershell - create template from string instead of file

Tags: xml, templates, powershell-2.0

I have the following powershell code. It basically creates a template, that I then use to populate with XML data.

```
$template = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <details>
        <cj></cj>
        <jn></jn>
        <en></en>
        <st></st>
        <et></et>
    </details>
</list>
'@

$template | Out-File template.xml -encoding UTF8

$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load("template.xml")
```

It works fine, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing this that doean't involve exporting it to a file and then loading that file back in.

e.g. is there a way of passing `$template` directly to the `$xml` (similar to `$xml.Load($template)` - which doesn't work)

I've had a look around the web, but can't find anything to help - am I just looking in the wrong places? or can it not be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit: oops... I'm on powershell version 3.0! Cannot say if this works on version 2.0, but it should!)

I think this way works:

```
$template = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <details>
        <cj></cj>
        <jn></jn>
        <en></en>
        <st></st>
        <et></et>
    </details>
</list>
'@

$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.LoadXml( $template )
```

Comment: cheers, it does indeed work perfectly. You'd think something as simple as that would be easy to find. . .